# How to override third party library's interface implementation?

Tags: java, spring, error-handling

Currently in my Spring project I'm using an external library, which provides its own error handler, which is an implementation of an interface. However, due to poor error handling implementation, I would prefer to implement the interface myself and then somehow instruct Java to use my own implementation instead of the provided one. Is something like this possible?

I tried to make a new class extending current error handler and override methods I want to change, but the overridden methods keep getting invoked instead of my own methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the class defined in an external library won't help you because the new class will have a different name and will not be used from the external library. (Unless you can edit their code - probably not an option?).

There is a trick however: you can implement your own class with exactly the same signature as the external one. Including the package tree.

Your class will be found by class loader **before** the external one and hence will be the only one used in application.